# How do I disable keyboard shortcuts in Trello?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to turn off keyboard shortcuts in Trello?

They break my regular navigation keys.

Comment: It could be possible to generally turn them off using generic methods such as those described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such option, sorry.

Comment: This is sad actually. I just accidentally put a card on the other list and there was no record on the activities also.

Comment: I've never ever wanted keyboard shortcuts on any website. I've only pressed them by accident and it's enraging that accidentally pressing a keyboard key does something like archives a card

Comment: yes, same for me. When view the message of the client and pressed some keyboard keys and card made archive.

Comment: See [this Chrome/Firefox plug-in solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169921)

Answer (score 4):

Atlassian hasn't implemented this feature since [acknowledging user feedback in 2017](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Is-it-possible-to-modify-or-disable-keyboard-shortcuts/qaq-p/589535#M465).

Fortunately, in 2022, GitHub user [SosthenG](https://github.com/SosthenG/) posted a browser plugin (for Chrome and Firefox) that disables all shortcuts on Trello (except tab, escape and enter).

**Github Repository:**   [Trello Shortcuts Killer](https://github.com/SosthenG/trello-shortcut-killer)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if Trello has an option for this but you can try tweaking your browser to disallow sites from binding keys. For example, this worked perfectly in my Opera (12.14, Linux): http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1083712&t=1363764906&page=1#comment10187842